# Unit тестирование Android приложения

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito, robolectric

Есть приложение секундомер: два активити и один сервис.

В первом активити есть кнопка для перехода на второе активити с хронометром.
В случае когда секундомер включен и при этом переходим на другое активити
счет времени продолжает `IntentService`, а когда возвращаемся - сервис останавливается,
берется с сервиса текущее время работы хронометра, устанавливается в хронометр и дальше
соответственно продолжается работа секундомера.

Вопрос какие места и каким образом (что для этого использовать) нужно тестировать в подобном приложении?

Достаточно ли для этого этих зависимостей, или нужны еще какие то инструменты?

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
```

Код приложения:

```
    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class ChronometrService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "ChronometrService";

    public static final String ACTION_RESUME_CLICK = "resumeClick";  // action for start service
    public static final String RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE = "sendResultToBroadcast"; // action for send result
    public static final String EXTRA_PARAM = "EXTRA_PARAM";

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(); // for looping Runnable thread
    public static boolean FLAG_ON = true; // flag for stop runnable thread

    private static long mTotalMilis; // the time that has elapsed since the pressing start button
    private long mLastMilis; // variable in which will writing time that was current in previous step
    private long mElapsedTime;  // in this variable will be writing difference of current and last(previous) time
    private long mCurrentMilis;

    public static long TIME = 0; // elapsed time which will be returned to ActivityChronometr (TIME ==  mTotalMilis)

    public ChronometrService() {
        super("ChronometrService");
    }

    // method for start service
    public static void resumeClick(Context context, long totalMilis) {
        mTotalMilis = totalMilis;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChronometrService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_RESUME_CLICK);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        System.out.println("OnStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        setTime(13);//todo delete line
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, action);
            switch (action) {
                case ACTION_RESUME_CLICK:
                    mLastMilis = mElapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
                    runnable.run();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (FLAG_ON) {
                mCurrentMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                mElapsedTime = mCurrentMilis - mLastMilis;
                mLastMilis = mCurrentMilis;
                mTotalMilis += mElapsedTime;

                setTime(mTotalMilis);
                sendResultToBroadcast(mTotalMilis);
                Log.d(TAG + " mTotalMilis =  " , String.valueOf(mTotalMilis));

                handler.postDelayed(this, 100); // 0.1 s
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }
    };

    // send result to BroadcastReceiver
    public void sendResultToBroadcast(long totalMilis) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM, totalMilis);
        LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        bm.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }


    public static long getTime() {
        return TIME;
    }

    public static void setTime(long time) {
        ChronometrService.TIME = time;
    }

}





    public class ChronometrActivity extends Activity {

    public static String TAG = "ChronometrActivity";

    public static String LONG_TAG = "longTag";
    public static String BOOLEAN_TAG = "booleanTag";

    private Button btnBack, btnStart, btnStop;
    private Chronometer chronometer;

    private boolean isStoped = false; // set false - to stop chronometr and true - to reset
    private boolean onPauseClick = true; // set true if Stop button was pressed, false if unpressed
    private long elapsedMillis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
        Log.d("onCreate() ", " Start");
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        // initialize view's  and listeners
        init();

        // if time !=0 it means that service was running and need
        // set the time and continue to work chronometer
        if (!(ChronometrService.getTime() == 0)) {
            elapsedMillis = ChronometrService.getTime();
            onPauseClick = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(BOOLEAN_TAG, false);

            if (onPauseClick){
                long tmp = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedMillis;
                chronometer.setBase(tmp);
                stopClick(btnStop);
                isStoped = true; // set stop button in stopped state
            }else{
                startClick(btnStart);
            }
        }

        // FLAG_ON = false  is stop Runnable thread
        ChronometrService.FLAG_ON = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("onResume() ", " Start");
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ChronometrService.RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("onPause() ", " Start");
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private void init() {



        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ChronometrService.RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE);
        LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        bm.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChronometrActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                if (!onPauseClick){
                    ChronometrService.resumeClick(getApplicationContext(), elapsedMillis);
                    ChronometrService.FLAG_ON = true;
                }else {
                    // add to intent flag of Stop button was pressed
                    intent.putExtra(BOOLEAN_TAG,onPauseClick);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startClick(v);
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopClick(v);
            }
        });
    }


    // start chronometr
    public void startClick(View view) {
        long tmp = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedMillis;
        elapsedMillis = 0;
        chronometer.setBase(tmp);
        chronometer.start();
        onPauseClick = false; // unpressed Stop button
        isStoped = false; //set stop button in default state
    }

    // stop chronometr
    public void stopClick(View view) {
        if (!isStoped) {
            ChronometrService.setTime(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase());
            chronometer.stop();
            isStoped = true;
            onPauseClick = true;
        } else {
            resetClick(view);
            isStoped = false;
            onPauseClick = true;
        }
    }

    // reset chronometr
    public void resetClick(View view) {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        elapsedMillis = 0; // elapsed time = 0  set chronometr start value 0.00 after reset
        ChronometrService.setTime(0); // set current chronometr time in service
    }

    // receiver for receiving messages from service
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case ChronometrService.RESPONSE_FROM_SERVICE:
                    elapsedMillis = intent.getLongExtra(ChronometrService.EXTRA_PARAM, 123456);
                    startClick(btnStart);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnGo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);


        btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChronometrActivity.class)
                            .putExtra(ChronometrActivity.LONG_TAG, getIntent().getLongExtra(ChronometrActivity.LONG_TAG, 123))
                            .putExtra(ChronometrActivity.BOOLEAN_TAG, getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ChronometrActivity.BOOLEAN_TAG,false)));
            }
        });
    }
}
```